# Entity Framework Core multiple DbContext with cross reference

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to create a modular project in ASP.NET Core with Entity Framework Core. So, my plan is to have a base project which contains things like auth config, identity model. There would be multiple feature module project which can be activated depends on what the costumer bought.

The problem is how to solve the migration in the database. Modules would be all separated but they might needs base project. For example if the module want to reference a user for a record in the database.

I created a `CoreDbContext` (in the base project).

```cs
public class CoreDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<WeatherForecast> WeatherForecasts { get; set; }

    public CoreDbContext()
    {    }

    public CoreDbContext(DbContextOptions<CoreDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {    }
}

public class WeatherForecast
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int TemperatureC { get; set; }
    public int TemperatureF => 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);
    public string Summary { get; set; }
}
```

`MeasurementsDbContext` (this is the feature module project)

```cs
public class MeasurementsDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Measurement> Measurements { get; set; }

    public MeasurementsDbContext()
    {    }

    public MeasurementsDbContext(DbContextOptions<MeasurementsDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {    }
}

public class Measurement
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public WeatherForecast Weather { get; set; } //Heres the reference (FK)
}
```

Configured the project like this (Startup.cs)

```cs
services.AddDbContext<CoreDbContext>(
    options =>
    {
        options.UseNpgsql(npsqlConnectionString, b =>
        {
            b.MigrationsAssembly("Core");
        });
    }
    );

services.AddDbContext<MeasurementsDbContext>(
    options =>
    {
        options.UseNpgsql(npsqlConnectionString, b =>
        {
            b.MigrationsAssembly("Measurements");
        });
    }
    );
```

**The problem:**

EF wants to create a table for the `WeatherForecast` class in the `Measurement` module, so it will be duplicated because the Core (base project) also creates it.

**My questions are:**

1. Can I solve this to generate the proper migration file? Or maybe I have to "hack" the migration file or this a bad practice?
2. `DbContext` should have there separated databases? Is the way I want to achieve this against the EF Core conventions / rules?
3. What do you suggest to make this kind of modular project? (I would prefer not to use micro services)

Comment: Generally, I prefer to use Multiple DBContext only if the application is extream large. And always divides entities in both contexts such that it does not have any relationship. So it does not generate such kind of conflict.

Comment: It will be a kind of huge project ( as far as I can appreciate ). But anyway because i want to sell it by modules it makes me do like this. 
Or maybe i should make all the models and the integration in one project and there will be empty tables. But it's not so elegant i guess.